# Select checkbox on load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

After I load all topics from the database I need to select the ones for specific user. How can I do that?

```
<div ng-repeat="item in topicEditItems">
    <md-checkbox ng-checked="existsEditTopic(item, topicEditSelected);" ng-click="toggleEditTopic(item, topicEditSelected);" value="{{item.TopicID}}">
        {{item.TopicName}}
    </md-checkbox>
</div>

$scope.topicEditSelected = [];

adminService.getTopics().then(function (response) {
    $scope.topicEditItems = $.parseJSON(response.data);
    //Select topics
})

$scope.toggleEditTopic = function (item, list) {
    var idx = list.indexOf(item);
    if (idx > -1) {
        list.splice(idx, 1);
    }
    else {
        list.push(item);
    }
};

$scope.existsEditTopic = function (item, list) {
    return list.indexOf(item) > -1;
};
```

Comment: So what is the propble?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is having 2 checkbox mimic to the original 1 then show and hide based on your filter. You may need to apply md-checkbox styling into the fake one

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check"  aria-label="Cb user" 
   ng-model="cbFake"  ng-if="isTopicExist(item.id)" ng-checked="isTopicExist(item.id)"/> 

<md-checkbox ng-checked="exists(item, selected)" ng-click="toggle(item, selected)" aria-label="Cb user" 
  ng-model="cbOri"  ng-if="!isTopicExist(item.id)"> </md-checkbox>
```

Answer (score -1):

update `$scope.existsEditTopic` to

```
  $scope.existsEditTopic = function (item, list) {
     var index = list.indexOf(item);
     if(index > -1){
        return true;
     }else{
        return false;                
      }
};
```

Comment: Thank you. Are you sure that will work. The user has to have the ability to check different boxes and I already have function for ng-checked.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D check this link also 
http://jsfiddle.net/niden/LD9Bt/

Comment: If I have four different topics and for this user 2 of them are selected in the database. How can I check these two check boxes on load.

Comment: after getting value from database do same thing.